# Bootstrapping Confidence Envelope for Binary Logistic Model in R

Tags: r, matlab, logistic-regression, predict, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a lower and upper 95% CI for a binary logistic regression model in R for some biological data. The response is pregnancy state based on hormone values, so an individual is either pregnant (1) or not (0). I then predict a series of unknown values across the model to get probabilities of pregnancy for individuals. I need to get/develop a 95% upper and lower CI envelope for the model and plot it. I have been able to do this in Matlab but can not get it to work in R using the bootstrap function to develop 1000 replicates from a vector/array of values that I can then take the upper .975 and lower .025 of to develop my CIs. Any help and feedback would be great. Thanks a bunch.

R code:

```
model5 <-glm(Preg~logP4, data = controls, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(model5)
range(controls$logP4)
xlogP4 <- seq(-1, 3, 0.01)
ylogP4 <- predict(model5, list(logP4=xlogP4, type ="response"))
plot(controls$logP4, controls$Preg, pch =16, xlab ="Log10(Progesterone)", ylab ="Probability of being pregnant")
curve(predict(model5, data.frame(logP4=x), type="resp"), add=TRUE)
```

Matlab code:

```
data = GoMControlsFinal;

x = data(1:29,4)%logP4 value
X = table2array(x)
y = data(1:29,6)% pregnant binary response
Y = table2array(y)
x1 = (-1:0.001:3)'

[b,dev,stats] = glmfit(X,Y,'binomial', 'logit') % linear regression analysis
yfit = glmval(b, x1, 'logit') % linear regression analysis


 %% not yet giving me a P of 0 to 1 for pregnancy, still working as linear model
for i=1:10000 %number of replicates
b2 = bootstrp(1,@glmBfit,X,Y); %generates bootstrap error envelop  
yfitBoot(:,i) = glmval(b2', x1, 'logit');
%plot (x1, yfitBoot(:,i), '-','LineWidth',1)
end

s =sort(yfitBoot');
s_lo = s(250,:) %number of replicates * 0.025
s_hi = s(9750,:)%number of replicates * 0.975
s_lo3 = s_lo'
s_hi3 = s_hi'

figure
z1= plot(x1, s_lo, 'b:', 'linewidth',2) % CI low line
hold on
z2 = plot(x1, s_hi, 'b:', 'linewidth',2) %ci hi line
z3= plot (x1, yfit, 'k-', 'LineWidth',2) % Model line
z4=scatter(X,Y, 'r', 'filled')
legend([z1, z3, z4], {'95% CI','Logistic Model', 'GoM Control Samples'})
xlabel('Log10 progesterone concentration')
ylabel('Probability of being pregnant')
```